# How to create module mutil languages with i18n in Drupal 7.x

Tags: drupal, internationalization

I want create once module multi languages in drupal 7.x with i18n installed already.
Please help me step by step create that,

Thanks advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home for all Drupal localization is now http://localize.drupal.org/.  This is a good place to start reading about internationalization and translation.

As a developer, you should also look at the Drupal 7 i18n articles by kristen: http://www.kristen.org/drupal7-i18n-articles,

Also read this about .po files: http://drupal.org/node/1814954

The very short version of what you need to know as a developer :-) is that you should wrap the strings you want to translatable in the translate (t()) function, as shown here: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-jan-25/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-3-localization-and-language-apis, and then translate the strings into the languages you're interested in by one of the means described below:

If you're translatable strings are part of an official Drupal project, translations contributed to http://localize.drupal.org/ will show up on your site next time translations are updated (there seems to be some delay of max 24 hours from a translation is accepted at http://localize.drupal.org/ to when updating has an effect).  Updating can be configured to happen automatically with localization update: http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update

For custom modules, you can upload your own translations through the administrative interface of the same module (localization update).